# How to add qwidget to qlist<qwidget>

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have several widgets, like

```
QLineEdit           m_namePoiFilter;
QLineEdit           m_ID_MSSIPoiFilter;
```

I would like to add them to a list of qwidgets, then set all of them visible.

I have made

```
QList<QWidget>      m_PoiFilterWidgets;
```

but I can not add an item to it like

```
m_PoiFilterWidgets.push_back(m_namePoiFilter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold these via a pointer, and you should use a lower-overhead container like `std::array`. E.g.:

```
class Foo {
   QLineEdit m_namePoiFilter;
   QLineEdit m_ID_MSSIPoiFilter;
   std::array<QLineEdit*, 2> const m_edits = {&m_namePoiFilter, &m_ID_MSSIPoiFilter};
};
```

This code is safe from dangling pointers by construction: `m_edits` will be constructed after the widgets are constructed, and will be destroyed before the widgets are destroyed: thus its contents are always valid.

I'd avoid `QList`/`QVector` as these allocate on the heap - unnecessarily in your case.

Answer (score 0):

QObjects, from which QWidgets are defined, are non-copyable. This means that you must store them in a list as pointers to widgets (i.e. `QList<QWidget *>`).

Comment: can you show an example please, with setting the visibility ?

Comment: Just iterate over every element in the list, and for each element use `setVisible(true)` or `show`.